# OnClick Java Script Button - If field equals x then update other field to a, else update other field to B

Tags: javascript, button, if-statement, onclick

I am working in a custom object and new to JavaScript.  I want to create a button that basically says if a field equals "x" then update a different field to "A", if that field equals "y" then update the other field to "B", if the field is null then send an alert.

I got the button to work to update the field I need, but when I tried to create the if/then I got syntax errors.

Here is what I have so far:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/27.0/connection.js")} 
var objPrice_Quote__c = new sforce.SObject('Price_Quote__c'); 
objPrice_Quote__c.Id = '{!Price_Quote__c.Id}'; 
objPrice_Quote__c.Status__c = 'Customer Approval'; 
var result = sforce.connection.update([objPrice_Quote__c]); 
location.reload(true);
```

Comment: It's probably worth mentioning that you are working in a SalesForce app - this is not immediately obvious from the question!

Comment: Sorry yes this is in Salesforce

Answer (score 1):

I don't even see an if statement within your code.... try this.

```
var theFieldToSet = document.getElementById("field1");
var button = document.getElementById("button");

button.onclick = function () {
    if (theFieldToSet.innerHTML == "x") {
        theFieldToSet.innerHTML = "A";
    }
};
```

Comment: I am sorry but like I said I am new to this and I do not understand your code on when I put my own information in.  I haven't listed an if statement yet because I couldn't get it to work.  

I want it to say something like this:
If fieldX equals A then updated fieldY to 1
If fieldX equals B then update fieldY to 2
If fieldX is NULL then give alert

Comment: The above code couldn't be anymore straight forward. I suggest watching some JavaScript tutorials and DOM manipulation before posting anymore questions about JavaScript.

Comment: Try watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5gjr15aWp24 This is a super basic tutorial about using an if statement. If statements are MUST to understand in any computer language.